# Erro: 404 Bad request Mongo, Express, Angular, Node

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a problem I can not solve, my application is returning the error 400 bad request, where I can not do any post, but using the postman it works normally I can do get, post, put, delete, but in my application does not Make it possible to do the post, I have done and redid the code several times and the problem is not remedied, I need to solve this

**My Controller**

```
angular.module('primeiraApp').controller('CarCycleCtrl', [
  '$scope',
  '$http',
  '$location',
  'msgs',
  'tabs',
  'consts',
  CarCycleController
])

function CarCycleController($scope, $http, $location, msgs, tabs, consts) {

  $scope.getCarCycles = function() {
    const page = parseInt($location.search().page) || 1
    const url = `${consts.apiUrl}/carCycles?skip=${(page - 1) * 10}&limit=10`
    $http.get(url).then(function(resp) {
      $scope.carCycles = resp.data
      $scope.carCycle = {}
      initCarsAndOuts()
      $http.get(`${consts.apiUrl}/carCycles/count`).then(function(resp) {
        $scope.pages = Math.ceil(resp.data.value / 10)
        tabs.show($scope, {tabList: true, tabCreate: true})
      })
    })
  }

  $scope.createCarCycle = function(){
    const url = `${consts.apiUrl}/carCycles`;
    $http.post(url,$scope.carCycle).then(function(response){
      $scope.carCycle = {}
      initCarsAndOuts()
      $scope.getCarCycles()
      msgs.addSuccess('Operação realizada com sucesso!')
    }).catch(function(resp){
      msgs.addError(resp.data.errors)
    })
  }

  $scope.showTabUpdate = function(carCycle) {
    $scope.carCycle = carCycle
    initCarsAndOuts()
    tabs.show($scope, {tabUpdate: true})
  }

  $scope.updateCarCycle = function() {
    const url = `${consts.apiUrl}/carCycles/${$scope.carCycle._id}`
    $http.put(url, $scope.carCycle).then(function(response) {
      $scope.carCycle = {}
      initCarsAndOuts()
      $scope.getCarCycles()
      tabs.show($scope, {tabList: true, tabCreate: true})
      msgs.addSuccess('Operação realizada com sucesso!')
    }).catch(function(resp) {
      msgs.addError(resp.data.errors)
    })
  }

  $scope.showTabDelete = function(carCycle) {
    $scope.carCycle = carCycle
    initCarsAndOuts()
    tabs.show($scope, {tabDelete: true})
  }

  $scope.deleteCarCycle = function() {
    const url = `${consts.apiUrl}/carCycles/${$scope.carCycle._id}`
    $http.delete(url, $scope.carCycle).then(function(response) {
       $scope.carCycle = {}
       initCarsAndOuts()
       $scope.getCarCycles()
       tabs.show($scope, {tabList: true, tabCreate: true})
       msgs.addSuccess('Operação realizada com sucesso!')
    }).catch(function(resp) {
       msgs.addError(resp.data)
    })
  }

  $scope.addDebt = function(index) {
    $scope.carCycle.outs.splice(index + 1, 0, {})
  }

  $scope.cloneDebt = function(index, {name, value, status}) {
    $scope.carCycle.outs.splice(index + 1, 0, {name, value, status})
    initCarsAndOuts()
  }

  $scope.deleteDebt = function(index) {
    $scope.carCycle.outs.splice(index, 1)
    initCarsAndOuts()
  }

  $scope.addCredit = function(index) {
    $scope.carCycle.cars.splice(index + 1, 0, {name: null, value: null})
  }

  $scope.cloneCredit = function(index, {name, value}) {
    $scope.carCycle.cars.splice(index + 1, 0, {name, value})
    initCarsAndOuts()
  }

  $scope.deleteCredit = function(index) {
    $scope.carCycle.cars.splice(index, 1)
    initCarsAndOuts()
  }

  $scope.cancel = function() {
    tabs.show($scope, {tabList: true, tabCreate: true})
    $scope.carCycle = {}
    initCarsAndOuts()
  }

  $scope.calculateValues = function() {
    $scope.car = 0
    $scope.out = 0

    if($scope.carCycle) {
      $scope.carCycle.cars.forEach(function({value}) {
        $scope.car += !value || isNaN(value) ? 0 : parseFloat(value)
      })

      $scope.carCycle.outs.forEach(function({value}) {
        $scope.out += !value || isNaN(value) ? 0 : parseFloat(value)
      })
    }

    $scope.total = $scope.car - $scope.out
  }

  var initCarsAndOuts = function() {
    if(!$scope.carCycle.outs || !$scope.carCycle.outs.length) {
      $scope.carCycle.outs = []
      $scope.carCycle.outs.push({})
    }

    if(!$scope.carCycle.cars || !$scope.carCycle.cars.length) {
      $scope.carCycle.cars = []
      $scope.carCycle.cars.push({})
    }

    $scope.calculateValues()
  }

  $scope.getCarCycles()
}
```

**My Backend**

```
const _ = require('lodash')
const CarCycle = require('./carCycle')

CarCycle.methods(['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete'])
CarCycle.updateOptions({new: true, runValidators: true})

CarCycle.after('post', sendErrorsOrNext).after('put', sendErrorsOrNext)

function sendErrorsOrNext(err, req, res, next) {
  const bundle = res.locals.bundle
  if(bundle.errors) {
    var errors = parseErrors(bundle.errors)
    res.status(500).json({errors})
  } else {
    next()
  }
}

function parseErrors(nodeRestfulErrors) {
  const errors = []
  _.forIn(nodeRestfulErrors, error => errors.push(error.message))
  return errors
}

CarCycle.route('count', function(req, res, next) {
  CarCycle.count(function(error, value) {
    if(error) {
      res.status(500).json({errors: [error]})
    } else {
      res.json({value})
    }
  })
})

module.exports = CarCycle
```